# Obtain a data from a variable inside a struct in a different class Swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I'm trying to obtain data from variables inside this structure for my UITableView cells

```
struct Issue {
 var id: String
 var tester: String
 var type: issueType
 var title: String
 var appName: String
 var desc: String
 var date: Date

 static func type(_ item: issueType) -> String {
     if item == .major {
         return "major"
     }
     else if item == .blocker {
         return "blocker"
     }
     else if item == .minor {
         return "minor"
     }
     return ""
 }
}
```

But every time i try to get the data for  my label, it didn't show up. Here's the code from my viewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)

    let item = array[indexPath.row]

    let topLine = cell.viewWithTag(1)
    let labelStatus = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    let labelTester = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
    let labelTitle = cell.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
    let labelAppName = cell.viewWithTag(5) as! UILabel
    let labelDesc = cell.viewWithTag(6) as! UILabel
    let labelDate = cell.viewWithTag(7) as! UILabel
    let labelId = cell.viewWithTag(8) as! UILabel

    labelStatus.text = Issue.type(item.type).capitalized
    labelTester.text = Issue.tester

    return cell

}
```

P.S. The labelStatus text works fine

Comment: You should use a `switch`. I guess there is a different issue type, a `switch` would show you that. Also, there is no reason to use a static method, use a normal method and `self.type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting text of `labelStatus` works, because you're calling static function on type `Issue` and this function returns `String`. In the second case you're trying to get property of type of struct, not of your certain `item`.

Use `item`'s property

```
labelTester.text = item.tester
```

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks! learn something new everyday, but I wonder how the "item" works? I mean I only declare it as an issueType

Comment: @Nodoodle `array` is array of `Issue` objects, and `item` is certain `Issue` object in this array with index equal to `indexPath.row`. This `item` has properties `type`, `tester`, etc.